# Where on earth is this image from the backgrounds in Windows?

Tags: turkey, where-on-earth, lock-screens

My Russian colleague had this image as his desktop, so I asked if it was Lake Baikal or not. He actually didn't know, as it was just one of the default Windows desktops that he had.

So, the question is, where on earth is it? I've tried a [tineye](https://www.tineye.com/) and [Google image](https://images.google.com/) search, but to no avail yet.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, a search-by-picture on Google answers: _windows 8.1 desktop_

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a picture of a sunrise on the coast of [Lycia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lycia), a Turkish region on the Mediterranean coast.

Source (click on the picture you've provided, it will show you the details):
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/beaches-panoramic-download-theme

Comment: Great answer. It provides exactly the requested information and more, while being only slightly longer than this comment.