# Identify the building in this picture

Tags: usa, identify-this, architecture

Does anyone know what building is shown in the picture below?

[image: a statue in front of a ?neo-classical building]

Comment: Is identifying buildings in scope of travel.se?

Comment: The image seems to have been used, without credit to any source, by [this individual's web site](http://i2.wp.com/www.nicholasdrillman.com/nicholasdrillman/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Recording-Your-Sets.jpg?w=1024). Ask directly about the image, which will help you to identify where it may have been taken.

Comment: got the picture from library of congress and im just interested what it is

Comment: If all the 'where is the Windows desktop background image from' questions are on-topic, why not this question as well? Here, exactly the same context and when asked by Mark Mayo worth +23 votes: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24305/where-on-earth-is-this-image-from-the-backgrounds-in-windows

Comment: In what Library of Congress collection was it in? And, forgive me for this, have you asked the Library of Congress, lthe collection archivist?

Comment: @RoryAlsop if it isn't then there's [a lot of closing to do](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the [Eisenhower Executive Office Bldg](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/USA-Executive_Office_Building.jpg) in Washington DC

Comment: I agree. The 1600 block of Pennsylvania Avenue, the EOB. Used to pass by it every day...